# Implementing The 'Learning To Read With Tensorflow' Talk From TF Summit 2020 - EncoderDecoder Seq2Seq Model In Tensorflow 2.1/2.2 - Custom Train Step

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, encoder-decoder, gradienttape

---

### Background Info

---

I am creating **Google Colabs** for each talk I found interesting from the Tensorflow 2020 Summit. As a note, I am using Tensorflow 2.1.

---

***I have encountered a problem when attempting to implement the `'Learning To Read With Tensorflow'` talk.***

---

Everything is peachy up until we get to the **`EncoderDecoder`** class definition. When I implement the fit method on my custom **`Model`** subclass I get an error which will be detailed below.

The last salient error is **`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'`**.

However, I believe this is due to a problem within the **`GradientTape`** scope code and/or problems with the definition of the **`Decoder Layers`** (including the **`Attention Layers`**)

---

### **Main Code**

```py
# Not normally defined here... but doing so for clarity
MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 5000
WINDOW_LENGTH = 11

class EncoderDecoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, 
                 max_features=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, 
                 output_seq_len=WINDOW_LENGTH-1,
                 embedding_dims=200,
                 rnn_units=512):

        super().__init__()

        self.max_features = max_features
        self.output_seq_len = output_seq_len
        self.embedding_dims = embedding_dims
        self.rnn_units = rnn_units

        self.vectorize_layer = \
            tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
                max_tokens=self.max_features,
                standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                split='whitespace', 
                ngrams=None, 
                output_mode='int',
                output_sequence_length=self.output_seq_len, 
                pad_to_max_tokens=True)

        # --- <ENCODER STUFF> ---
        # Embedding
        self.encoder_embedding = \
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=self.max_features+1,
                                      output_dim=self.embedding_dims)

        # ENCODER
        self.lstm_layer = \
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=self.rnn_units, 
                                 return_state=True)
        # --- </ENCODER STUFF> ---        

        # --- <DECODER STUFF> ---
        # Embedding
        self.decoder_embedding = \
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=self.max_features+1,
                                      output_dim=self.embedding_dims)

        # ---------------- MAYBE NOT NECESSARY ----------------
        # Sampler (for use during training)
        # This was not shown during the talk but it is pretty obvious
        sampler = tfa.seq2seq.sampler.TrainingSampler()

        # This was not shown during the talk but is required... 
        # This is my best guess
        decoder_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units=self.rnn_units)
        # ---------------- MAYBE NOT NECESSARY ----------------

        # Output Layer For Decoder
        self.projection_layer = \
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.max_features)

        # DECODER
        self.decoder = \
            tfa.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=decoder_cell,
                                     sampler=sampler,
                                     output_layer=self.projection_layer)
        # --- </DECODER STUFF> ---

        # --- <ATTN STUFF> ---
        # Basic dense attention layer to connect Encoder & Decoder
        self.attention = tf.keras.layers.Attention()
        # --- </ATTN STUFF> ---

    def train_step(self, data):
        """ Overwrite built-in train_step method

        Args:
            data (tuple): The example (ten `words`), and the label (one `word`)

        Returns:
            Metric results for all passed metrics
        """

        # Split data into example (x) and label (y)
        x, y = data[0], data[1]

        # Vectorize the example words (x)
        x = self.vectorize_layer(x)

        # Vectorize the labels
        # This will by default pad the output to 10 ... but we only need the
        # first entry (the true label not the useless padding)
        y = self.vectorize_layer(y)[:, 0]

        # Convert our label into a one-hot encoding based on the max number of
        # features that we will be using for our model
        y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y, self.max_features)

        # Everything within GradientTape is recorded 
        # for later automatic differentiation
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # --- <ENCODER STUFF> ---

            # Transform the example utilizing the encoder embedding
            inputs = self.encoder_embedding(x)

            # Get the encoder outputs and state by 
            # utilizing the encoder (lstm_layer)
            #   - encoder_outputs : [max_time, batch_size, num_units]
            #   - encoder_state   : [state_h, state_c]
            #       * state_h --- The Hidden State
            #       * state_c --- The Cell   State
            encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = self.lstm_layer(inputs)

            # --- </ENCODER STUFF> ---

            # --- <ATTN STUFF> ---

            # Pass the encoder outputs and hidden state allowing us
            # to track the intermediate state coming out of the encoder layers
            attn_output = self.attention([encoder_outputs, state_h])
            attn_output = tf.expand_dims(attn_output, axis=1)

            # --- </ATTN STUFF> ---

            # --- <DECODER STUFF> ---

            # ??? Create an empty embedding ???
            targets = self.decoder_embedding(tf.zeros_like(y))

            # Concat the output of the attention layer to the last axis
            # of the empty targets embedding
            concat_output = tf.concat([targets, attn_output], axis=-1)

            # Predict the targets using the state from the encoder
            outputs, _, _ = \
                self.decoder(concat_output, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])

            # --- </DECODER STUFF> ---

        # Automatically differeniate utilizing the loss and trainable variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)

        # Collect the outputs so that they can be optimized
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))

        # Update the metric state prior to return
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y_one_hot, y_pred)

        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}


model = EncoderDecoder()

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.vectorize_layer.adapt(lines.batch(256))

# ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
model.fit(data.batch(256),
          epochs=45,
          callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='text_gen')])
```

---

### **Detailed Error Message**

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-779906f7f617> in <module>()
      1 model.fit(data.batch(256),
      2           epochs=45,
----> 3           callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='text_gen')])

8 frames
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    233           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    234           workers=workers,
--> 235           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    236 
    237       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, steps_per_epoch, validation_split, validation_data, validation_steps, shuffle, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    591         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    592         workers=workers,
--> 593         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    594     val_adapter = None
    595     if validation_data:

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in _process_inputs(model, mode, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    704       max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    705       workers=workers,
--> 706       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    707 
    708   return adapter

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, standardize_function, **kwargs)
    700 
    701     if standardize_function is not None:
--> 702       x = standardize_function(x)
    703 
    704     # Note that the dataset instance is immutable, its fine to reusing the user

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in standardize_function(dataset)
    658         model.sample_weight_mode = getattr(model, 'sample_weight_mode', None)
    659 
--> 660       standardize(dataset, extract_tensors_from_dataset=False)
    661 
    662       # Then we map using only the tensor standardization portion.

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2358     is_compile_called = False
   2359     if not self._is_compiled and self.optimizer:
-> 2360       self._compile_from_inputs(all_inputs, y_input, x, y)
   2361       is_compile_called = True
   2362 

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _compile_from_inputs(self, all_inputs, target, orig_inputs, orig_target)
   2578       if training_utils.has_tensors(target):
   2579         target = training_utils.cast_if_floating_dtype_and_mismatch(
-> 2580             target, self.outputs)
   2581       training_utils.validate_input_types(target, orig_target,
   2582                                           allow_dict=False, field_name='target')

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in cast_if_floating_dtype_and_mismatch(targets, outputs)
   1334   if tensor_util.is_tensor(targets):
   1335     # There is one target, so output[0] should be the only output.
-> 1336     return cast_single_tensor(targets, dtype=outputs[0].dtype)
   1337   new_targets = []
   1338   for target, out in zip(targets, outputs):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

---

### **How To Get `data` & `lines` Variables If Wishing To Replicate**

**Get the Data**

```sh
>>> wget http://www.thespermwhale.com/jaseweston/babi/CBTest.tgz
>>> tar zxvf CBTest.tgz
>>> rm -rf CBTest.tgz
```

**Preprocess The Data**

```py
# Load data from a dataset comprising lines 
# from one or more text files.
lines = tf.data.TextLineDataset("<path-to>/cbt_train.txt")

# Filter Out Title Lines First 
# This simple fn not included in this stackoverflow code
lines = lines.filter(lambda x: not is_title(x))

# Then We Remove All Punctuation 
# This simple fn not included in this stackoverflow code
lines = lines.map(lambda x: remove_punc(x))

# Then We Remove All Extra Spaces Created By The Previous FN
# This simple fn not included in this stackoverflow code
lines = lines.map(lambda x: remove_extra_spaces(x))

# Then We Turn All The Uppercase Letters into Lowercase Letters
# This simple fn not included in this stackoverflow code
lines = lines.map(lambda x: make_lower(x))

# Get words from lines
words = lines.map(tf.strings.split)
words = words.unbatch()

# Get wordsets
wordsets = words.batch(11)

# get_example_label is a simple fn to split wordsets into examples and labels
# First ten words are the example and last word is the label
data = wordsets.map(get_example_label)

# Shuffle
data = data.shuffle(1024)
```

**References**

---

- [Tensorflow Seq2Seq ReadMe](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/README.md)
- [Youtube Video For the Tensorflow Summit Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNrqaOAt5P4&list=PLQY2H8rRoyvzuJw20FG82Lgm2SZjTdIXU&index=3&t=0s)

---

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

It appears as though Tensorflow has released tutorials detailing all of the demos that were conducted at the Summit.

The result is that you can examine the actual code and determine the differences between theirs and yours. I won't post the differences here because they are more significant than I initially thought

---

#### Links

- **[General Dev Summit Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/dev-summit-2020/)**
- **[Learning To Read With Tensorflow Github Notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/dev-summit-2020/learning_to_read_with_tensorFlow_and_keras.ipynb)**

---

#### Additional Resources

When I contacted Tensorflow they also recommended that I check out the **[transformer tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer)** which goes into detail on how to implement complex encoder-decoder and self-attention networks.

- Additionally they pointed me at their **[TF2 implementation of BERT](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/nlp/bert)** so I will include that link as well.

---

**Hope these resources help you out!**